# C++ Replacing a word in an array of characters

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm working on a problem where I need to have user input a message then replace the work "see" with "c". I wanted to read in the array message[200] and then break it down into individule words. I tried a for loop but when I concatinate it just adds the privous words. I am only to use array of characters, no strings.

```
const int MAX_SIZE = 200;

int main(){

    char message[MAX_SIZE]; //message array the user will enter
    int length;     // count of message lenght
    int counter, i, j;      //counters for loops
    char updateMessage[MAX_SIZE];   //message after txt update

    //prompt user to
    cout << "Please type a sentence" << endl;
    cin.get(message, MAX_SIZE, '\n');
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');

    length = strlen(message);
    //Lower all characters
    for( i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        message[i] = tolower(message[i]);


    //echo back sentence
    cout << "You typed: " << message << endl;
    cout << "Your message length is " << length << endl;

    for( counter = 0; counter <= length; ++counter)
    {

            updateMessage[counter] = message[counter];

            if(isspace(message[counter]) || message[counter] == '\0')
            {
                    cout << "Space Found" << endl;
                    cout << updateMessage << endl;
                    cout << updateMessage << " ** " << endl;

            }
    }
return 0;
}
```

After each space is found I would like to output one work each only.

Comment: "I would like to output one work each only" is not a question.

Comment: You are correct. Sorry. How do I output each word without concatination?

Comment: the only "C++" in this program is cout. This is actually C code.

Comment: Take out a blank piece of a paper, and a pencil. Write down, in plain English, a list of simple logical steps that implement the algorithm for doing what you want to do. Use short logical sentences, like "set variable A to B" and "repeat the following as a loop, from A to B", etc. Once you have completed your algorithm, [discuss it with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Once your rubber duck agrees that it will work, you can simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into code. Problem solved.

Comment: @dmg it has `cout`,  its c++, why would he tag it C?

Comment: Because your problem is related to C data structures and semantics. Not to C++. A C++ programmer would never use C arrays. Ever.

Comment: This is for a C++ class, hence the C++ tag

Comment: @dmg Why are you even making that point? It should be tagged as C++ and is...

Comment: Because this is C question, not a C++ question. If it was a C++ question the person would be using std::vector.

Comment: @dmg You said: "A C++ programmer would never use C arrays. Ever"  Really?  You _never_ use C arrays?  I'm just curious...

Comment: C++defines a data structure called std::array for those cases when you really want to use C style arrays. It is safer than bare C arrays. However it is a nuisance to use. . In C++ there is really no need to ever declare a C style array. Say you want to read from a file using a FILE *. You can simply declare a vector, initialize it to the size you want and then call it using fread(&myArray[0], myArray.size(), 1, file).  See the solution by vsoftco below for the proper way to solve this problem with C++

Comment: @Steph_B: thinking about it. There is only one exception, due to the legacy of C in C++: the second parameter to main is an array. Instead of using an array, use a vector. It is safer: you can use vec.size() and you can use vec[i] as usual. But you also get vec.at(i) that gives you runtime checking of the index to make sure you are not out of bounds. They have very little overhead over C arrays (in terms of performance) and have great functionality in the STD (see algorithms and functional).

Answer (score 1):

You should really try to learn some modern C++ and standard library features, so you don't end up writing C code in C++. As an example, this is how a C++14 program makes use of standard algorithms from the library to do the job in 10-15 lines of code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::string_literals;

    std::istringstream input("Hello I see you, now you see me");
    std::string str;

    // get the input from the stream (use std::cin if you read from console)
    std::getline(input, str);

    // tokenize
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    std::istringstream ss(str);
    for(std::string word ; ss >> word; words.push_back(word));

    // replace
    std::replace(words.begin(), words.end(), "see"s, "c"s);

    // flatten back to a string from the tokens
    str.clear();
    for(auto& elem: words)
    {
        str += elem + ' ';
    }

    // display the final string
    std::cout << str;
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8057da6aad6091d5)

This is not the most efficient way of doing it, as you can perform replacement in place, but the code is clear and if you don't need to save every bit of CPU cycles it performs decently.

Below is a solution that avoids the `std::vector` and performs the replacement in place:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream input("Hello I see you, now you see me");
    std::string str;

    // get the input from the stream (use std::cin if you read from console)
    std::getline(input, str);

    // tokenize and replace in place
    std::istringstream ss(str);
    std::string word;
    str.clear();
    while (ss >> word)
    {
        if (word == "see")
            str += std::string("c") + ' ';
        else
            str += word + ' ';
    }

    // display the final string
    std::cout << str;
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c8497c6372e7721)